Google Play consoler mobile number verification error "We can't verify your phone number right now"
I will try to verify my google play consoler duns number verification. But i cannot verify my mobile number. But my email should be verify. mobile number verification code should not came.We are based in Sri Lanka.
I send the email for googleplay-developer-support@google.com. they have no reply your email. Please help me to verify your account.our duns number and email are verfiy. but our deadline is 8th September 2024.

I am also facing the same issue, did you solve it?

No, I received an email from Google stating that they have extended our submission date to next year. This is a common issue for most Asian countries.
